# Expectation of a ratio of two independent variables

Tags: probability, intuition, expected-value

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, is it true that $$ E[\frac{X}{Y}] = E[X\cdot\frac{1}{Y}]=\text{cov}(X,\frac{1}{Y})+E[X]E[\frac{1}{Y}]$$ and therefore $$E[\frac{X}{Y}] =E[X]E[\frac{1}{Y}].$$
Any intuitive explanation of why the covariance is always zero?

What about $E[\frac{XY}{ZZ}]$ when $X$, $Y$, $Z$ are independent?

Comment: As a sidenote, I was reading about spurious correlation of ratios and got confused (corrr(X/Z, Y/Z) != 0, where X,Y,Z are independent)

Comment: $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is Borel. For any two Borel functions $f$ and $g$, $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ are independent if only $X$ and $Y$ are. Intuitively you can see it, as $X$ doesn't depend on $Y$, nor should $f(X)$ depend on $f(Y)$

Comment: It is important to notice that the existence of $\mathbb{E}[Y^{-1}]$ has to be well defined for you to be able to justify the computations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, the so are $X$ and $Z = f(Y) = \frac{1}{Y}$. Therefore, the $cov(X, \frac{1}{Y}) = cov(X,Z)$ is zero due to the independence between $X$ and $Z$. Also, recall that independence implies uncorrelatedness,